# Can't Print From Outlook, Printer always prompts the user before printing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, printing

I have a user that has a outlook specific problem. The user can print any and all documents perfectly fine. The document gets printed right away at the printer. However, when printing a pdf from outlook, the printer shows a prompt to continue before printing, thus the user has to walk over to the printer select OK and then it will start printing.

Any hints as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If the printer is told to print on a different paper size or type than is loaded in the tray, the printer may ask for permission to continue, or it may ask for the paper to be loaded in the bypass tray or the requested tray. The exact request depends on the printer model.

Check the paper settings (tray, paper size and paper type) in Outlook, and make sure they correspond to what's loaded in the printer. You can do this from Page Setup.

BTW I assume you mean Outlook - not Outlook.com or Outlook Express. Only M$ can think it's a good idea to give 3 different products the same name.

Comment: Yes i mean Outlook, not any of the other outlook product. lol.

I will try all of these ideas, thanks.